# How to export data from sqlite database created in Android Application to a .csv?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv, bluetooth

My android application (created in android studio), shows data from my device coming through bluetooth, using BLE. I wish to save this data in a csv(I used Sqlite database to store the data, my question is how to get the data from database exported to a .csv)

Comment: could you give us more information, like the type of data, or the columns in the database?  for now I can only give you a very generalized example.  Also, could the answer be in any language (i.e., python and sqlite3) or are you looking for a specific one?

Comment: Is this just for development so you can see what data is in your database? Or is this part of an actual feature? If it's just for yourself, there are probably easier ways to get that data.